# Get direct Google analytics url from Google Apps scripts analytics reporting call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I have this google apps script code:

```
var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:source',              
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '250'                     
};


var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
    tableId,                    
    "2014-07-14",                  
    "2014-07-14",                    
    'ga:newUsers', 
optArgs);
```

It works fine, I can get the number of new users. I want to get the url of this request where user can click on and be redirected to analytics dashboard where he can view the number of new users.

The data is just a sample, I need it to work for any request of course. Any ideas?